# Need US federal source for ZIP codes (not ZCTAs) including ZIP code type

Tags: geospatial, usa, data.gov, government, postal-code

I'm looking to locate either a published table or federally hosted API that returns current (and/or past, if available) ZIP codes that includes the ZIP code type (S/P/U/Z/etc). This data must be published by an agency of the federal government. I'm not looking for ZCTA shapefiles, just a list of active codes, their type, and ideally the address of the corresponding post office for P- and Z- type zip codes. I've checked data.gov but they do not appear to offer datasets from the USPS.

Most open geography datasources I have checked are based on ZCTA instead of the entire ZIP code universe (because they have to have polygon shapefiles, which I don't care about). This **does not work** for me, ZIP and ZCTA are separate systems even though they use the same unique identifier (ZIP5). ZCTAs are maintained by the census bureau as approximations of the delivery area of S-type zip codes, and exclude P-, U- and Z- type ZIP codes, which do not have a postal delivery area. I need a datasource that includes P- and Z- ZIP codes (I don't care about U-type zip codes or any other types, if any exist).

I can't use any source encumbered by restrictive terms of use and I don't want to use a commercial service for my project. I'd like my data to come directly from the Postal Service, or from another federal agency if no data is available from the Postal Service.

Comment: zip codes are proprietary data owned by USPS and that is why you can't find what you want and why you most likely will not.

Comment: How are we supposed to send mail if ZIP codes are "proprietary data"?

Comment: proprietary to get underlying source/code. not proprietary to use, afaik.